# What happened after the brief scene with Terry and Christina near the end of S01?

Tags: kingdom-2014

In [Kingdom (2014-17)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3673794/), near the end of S01E10 (near the end of the season), there is a brief scene where Terry pulls up in his car next to Christina:

> Terry: It's good to hear from you, love. I didn't think I would.

> Christina: I missed you, Terry.

> Terry: It's not me you fucking missed. Get in anyway. We'll get you fit again.

Christina then gets into Terry's car, suggesting she's going back to drugs and prostitution with Terry.

We don't see Terry again until S02E05, when Terry comes looking for Christina at Patty Burgers and it seems as if Christina hasn't done any drugs or been working with Terry ever since being "rescued" by Jay in S01. (Later in S02E06, Christina quits her job at Patty Burgers. In S02E07, she looks for Terry to get drugs and return to prostitution.)

Is this a continuity error? Or what was supposed to have happened after that brief scene we saw in S01E10?